# CruiseControl.NET check output for success messages

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

We have a very large legacy system which is built using complicated batch files.  Our CruiseControl.NET server simply calls the batch files and checks the return code, which works fine and produces a successful build.

Sometimes however the batch file doesn't seem to return properly after a successful build, and CruiseControl.NET simply hits the timeout and reports the build as failed.

Is there any way I can get CruiseControl.NET to check the output from the batch file for the string which indicates a successful build, and correctly report the status of the build?

(When I get a spare day or two I want to rewrite the build scripts using NAnt or something, but it's not been given a high priority since its so complicated, and it's currently working)

EDIT: this is the entry in ccnet.config

```
  <project name="MyProject" queue="Q1" queuePriority="1">
    <workingDirectory>D:\MyProject</workingDirectory>    
    <triggers />
    <tasks>
      <exec>
        <executable>buildexe.bat</executable>
        <baseDirectory>D:\MyProject</baseDirectory>
        <buildArgs>V12.8 MyProject</buildArgs>
        <buildTimeoutSeconds>6000</buildTimeoutSeconds>
        <successExitCodes>0</successExitCodes>
      </exec>
    </tasks>
    <publishers>
      <xmllogger logDir="D:\MyProject\logs\V12.8" />    
    </publishers>    
  </project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try explicitely setting the successexitscodes?

See http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Executable+Task

Comment: Yes, I have `<successExitCodes>0</successExitCodes>` and the batch file should set the return code to 0 if successful or 1+ for a failure.  It seems sometimes it just never finishes, although the batch file gets to the end of it's log, and it always seems to finish if you run it manually.

Comment: Arf. Could you locate the last executed task of your build batch using the xmllogger?

Comment: The logger does seem to include all the output from the batch file - all the way up to the point where it successfully returns, if you're running it from the console.

Comment: I'm running out of ideas here. I presume your script run time does not exceed 100 minutes and it returns 0 if successful (exit 0 or exit %ERRORLEVEL%)? Did you check the code line (computed by cc.net) which starts your batch script (can be seen in ccnet logs)?

Comment: the script outputs it's last line after approximately 25 mins.  It normally returns 0 but even should it exit with an errorlevel of 1 I would expect cruisecontrol to pick up after that point.  Perhaps I'm devoting too much effort after a lost cause here - time to bite bullet and rewrite with nant.

Comment: OK. It may be a very stupid idea but did you try to wrap your batch script inside a msbuild script (basically one target which call your .bat script)? It's 5min long to test it and it may solve your problem. All you have to do after is to use the CC .net MsBuild task to invoke your build script. Just an idea but if we have no hint/solution I think it's worth-trying

Comment: I've accepted your answer since it was helpful, but I did end up rewriting the build script, which is now better in many ways :)